# how to create many tables from an excel data source using python to transform data to feed a powerBI star schema and grantee updates in real time

Tags: python, powerbi, dashboard, auto-update, data-transform

I am working on a Power BI dashboard. My users are using an Excel to indicate their burdens in some projects. The Excel file contains columns that contain the burden for a specific month. For example, if we are examining the load of 2022 there will be 12 columns,each column stands for a month.
Here is an example
[image]

I need to visualize the burdens of users for time dimension, so I wrote a python script to generate a CSV that respects a star schema, so I generated a CSV that has 2 columns the date and the burdens.
Here is my file
[image]

that's an exemple, but I want to extract so many other tables. I thought to use python within powerBI but it is slow and each time I need to connect to my data source.

the problem with that solution is that i need to rerun the python script each time I want to update the file and I don't want to use an scheduler that will update the file on daily basis for exemple, but i need to run the python script each time the user modify or add a value so the modification appears in real time in the dashboard. Do u have any idea ?

Comment: If you are doing basic transformations, don't use python, use the inbuilt M/Power Query. If you want real time you'll need a database in direct query mode, rather than use an excel file, csv and python and you want it automated

Comment: I can't use a database cuz the users use the excel file and we can't remove it. so the excel file needs to be transformaed to have a star schema for my visualisation